# The "fade out" effect on "Recommended reading" is chopping off the bottom of the previous line

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

[image]

Note that the words `forget to follow. In` on the third line are chopped off a bit by the fade out of `"The Ten Rules of G`...

Comment: The `::after` CSS should have its height set to `1 em` instead of the current `1.5 em`.